# Patch imports in a module

Tags: python-2.7, import

In my project, I use exclusively `re` module and `json` module. We know that there are some 3rd-party libraries are faster than the built-in packages, e.g. `re2` or `pcre-re` might be faster than `re` and `ujson` might be faster than `json`, so I would like to use them if possible. Previously, the practice I used was:

```
try:
    import re2 as re
except ImportError:
    import re
```

It works, yet if I have a big project, I will have to patch *every* file which uses `re`. This is difficult and other contributers may forget to do such trick.

What I would like to do is, do something in `__init__.py`, or some other place, and let it patch the `re` and `json` library, so when I do `import re`, the patched version would automatically try to use `re2` and fallback to `re`. Is it possible? I am using Python 2.7, and we do not have any plan of upgrading to Python 3.